# JQuery Mobile - can we call POST web service on click of a button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

On click of a button, I am calling a web service POST method through JQUERY AJAX. Web service is in another domain. But this call is getting failed and not giving any response.

When i verify the network requests through browser, I can see the URL as

https://localsite://https://remotesite/webservicemethod.

If i call this same POST web service method in the page load, it's calling successfully. URL is correctly going as "http://remotesite/webservicemethod".

This is the method I am using:

```
_asyncPOST : function(url, dataObject, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type            : "POST",
            dataType    : "json",
            url             : url,
            data            : dataObject,
            success     : function(data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },
```

But i want to call this webservice method on click of a button.

Comment: ram us with some cod

Comment: your URLs can not useful to see anything please use pictures to show your problems

Comment: Hi Madalin, some part of the code is added in the post.

Comment: @Ram show the code where you call `_asyncPOST` in page load and on button click